# How to change div contenteditable from true to false

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I got a page which let user change the text inside div and save the html code into a database, however when I display back the html code I want to change the div `contenteditable` to false. Is there any way???

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ultra' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" ; />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="function.js"></script>

<h1>H1</h1>
<div class="drag">
  <div id="box" style="padding-left: 45px; background: url(2.png);">
    <div class="line-division1" style="margin-top: 100px; background-color: #003663;"></div>
    <div id="sub-title" contenteditable="true"><span>YOU'RE IN FOR A</span></div>
    <div id="title" contenteditable="true">Wild
      <font color="#90a6b9">Ride</font>
    </div>
    <div class="line-division1" style="margin-top: 20px; background-color: #003663;"></div>
    <div class="date1" contenteditable="true">THIS JANUARY 21ST 2014</div>
    <div class="date1" contenteditable="true">1337 ACCELERATOR, KL</div>
    <div class="line-division1" style="width: 150px; height:22px; float: left; background-color: #003663; margin-top: 50px;"></div>
    <div class="line-division1" style="width: 150px; height:22px; float: right; background-color: #003663; margin-top: 50px; margin-right: 50px;"></div>
    <div class="date1" style="font-size: 80px; width: 500px;" contenteditable="true">JOIN US</div>
    <br>
    <div class="date1" style="font-size: 38px; margin-top: 20px;">FOR A RIDE OF YOUR LIFE TIME</div>
    <img src="waterm.png" style="zoom:30%; margin-top: 280px; margin-left: 2000px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: describe your scenario better... you can always change it by document.getElementById("diviID").contenteditable=false;

Comment: when do you display back? though form submit....some more information is needed for proper answer... you can change it in php also...

Comment: you can achieve it easily with jquery

Comment: i display back the html code using php in another page.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since you have 5 elements with `contenteditable`, try giving them IDs to simplify access.

The following code deactivates the 5 `contentediable` elements:

```
var editable_elements = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=true]");
editable_elements[0].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
editable_elements[1].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
editable_elements[2].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
editable_elements[3].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
editable_elements[4].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/78jSw/3/)

Or you can you a loop

```
var editable_elements = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=true]");
for(var i=0; i<editable_elements.length; i++)
    editable_elements[i].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
```

Comment: wow work perfectly like i want in demo, but can you tell me where do i need to add this script in??

Comment: It should be added in the Javascript that comes after you successfully save to the database. I would assume that this is somewhere in "function.js".

Comment: I would use the id attribute, so I can access each element directly, or I'd preferably use a framework that simplifies this.

Comment: For those like me wondering why Typescript objects to this, the argument is actually a string ("true") not a boolean (true). Everything works fine with a bool, but it's not what the spec says. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable

Answer (score 4):

Even though you not tagged this question as jquery, you already asked if there is a way to do it. and my way to do it is using jquery.

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TpG74/1/)**

```
$('div').blur(function () {
    $(this).attr('contenteditable', false);
});
```

or after saving the div content to db. use this code below to edit all div with contenteditable attribute true to false.

Heres' the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TpG74/2/)**

```
$('div[contenteditable="true"]').attr('contenteditable', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

To do it on each elements with "contenteditable=true" you can simple try this:

```
var editableElements = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=true]");

for (var i = 0; i < editableElements.length; ++i) {
    editableElements[i].setAttribute("contentEditable", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work in all browser

```
 var arr=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;i++)
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].removeAttribute("contenteditable");
```

[**Working Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ynype/1/)

This will work in modern browser(but too much versatile)

```
for(var i=0;i<document.querySelectorAll("div").length;i++)
document.querySelectorAll("div")[i].removeAttribute("contenteditable");
```

[**Working Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ynype/4/)

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, not a single element.

Answer (score 0):

Ming,

You can use a Submit button at the end of your `Div`. So when the user is done with editing he can submit the form, you can do a post to save this text in database and also the button will make the content non-editable. Here I added a button to your code and a bit of jQuery.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="box" style="padding-left: 45px; background: url(2.png);">
<div class="line-division1" style="margin-top: 100px; background-color: #003663;">        </div>
<div id="sub-title" contenteditable="true"><span>YOU'RE IN FOR A</span></div>
<div id="title" contenteditable="true">Wild <font color="#90a6b9">Ride</font></div>
<div class="line-division1" style="margin-top: 20px; background-color: #003663;"></div>
<div class="date1" contenteditable="true">THIS JANUARY 21ST 2014</div>
<div class="date1" contenteditable="true">1337 ACCELERATOR, KL</div>
<div class="line-division1" style="width: 150px; height:22px; float: left; background-  color: #003663; margin-top: 50px;"></div>
<div class="line-division1" style="width: 150px; height:22px; float: right; background-color: #003663; margin-top: 50px; margin-right: 50px;"></div>
<div class="date1" style="font-size: 80px; width: 500px;" contenteditable="true">JOIN US</div>
</br>
<div class="date1" style="font-size: 38px; margin-top: 20px;">FOR A RIDE OF YOUR LIFE TIME</div>
<button text="Submit">Submit</button>
```

**jQuery** (just include a jquery file to your code)

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('div').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    });
});
```

Thats it !!!

[**Find a fiddle demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/XuBbU/)

Answer (score 0):

Do it one line with vanilla js

```
document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=true]").forEach(el => el.setAttribute("contentEditable", false))
```